# Mongodb 4 service will not start after setting auth - Error 1053

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDb 4 running fine as Service on win 10.
as soon as I set authorization: enabled
in the mongo config file:

```
C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.cfg
```

It was

```
#security:
```

I have set it to:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

The service will not start, and displaying Error 1053
[image: Error 1053]

I dont see anything in the server log or mongodb log
Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, but in my case what solved was replacing the tab for two spaces in the **authorization: enabled** line, like this:

```
# Configuration using TAB not working
security:
    authorization: enabled


# Configuration using two spaces working
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: I didnt expect this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.cfg
```

change

```
#snmp:
mp:
```

to

```
#snmp:
#mp:
```

it works for me.

Comment: mine was just `p:`, not `mp:`, but commenting out the `p` worked for me to solve the same issue. Thank you @CTD

Answer (score 2):

In my case I first commented it, it caused 1053 error, so I had to remove comment and set -

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by replacing the tab with two spaces and putting "enabled" between double quotes

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me MongoDB 4.2, this thing works to run the service on Windows 10.

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Not sure exactly but I think there is issue related to space and colon.